# How to access duplicate column names with JSTL sql:query?

Tags: java, sql, jsp, jstl

For some reason, this

```
    <sql:query dataSource="${ds}" sql="select user.id, user.name as userName, city, state, country, country.name as countryName, latitude, longitude, ip, last_visit from user, country where user.country = country.id order by last_visit desc limit 100" var="result"/>
    <c:forEach var="col" items="${result.columnNames}">
        ${col}, 
    </c:forEach>
```

produces

```
id, name, city, state, country, name, latitude, longitude, ip, last_visit,
```

Which is wrong. I specifically renamed the columns in the query. I don't know how it found the original field name. So how can I access the value of user.name? `${row.userName}` doesn't work.

I'm using JSTL jstl-1.2.2.

Comment: This actually works, but I'm not happy about it: `<c:forEach var="rows" items="${result.rowsByIndex}">
   ${rows[1]}, ${rows[5]}<br>
  </c:forEach>`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure if this will help, but I've read that using aliases will not always work correctly.  A possible alternative I've seen:

```
 <sql:query dataSource="${ds}" sql="select user.id, concat(user.name,'') as userName, city, state, country, concat(country.name,'') as countryName, latitude, longitude, ip, last_visit from user, country where user.country = country.id order by last_visit desc limit 100" var="result"/>
    <c:forEach var="col" items="${result.columnNames}">
        ${col}, 
    </c:forEach>
```

Hope this helps.  Good luck.

Comment: Genius! This must be a bug!

Comment: Why is not the bug solved? Java in general is so important and Java EE as well.