# foreach not recognize aliases in loop database query

Tags: jsp, foreach, jstl

Hello I'm susing jstl foreach an have the follow query:

```
<sql:query var="calendario" dataSource="jdbc/pro-level">
                    SELECT DISTINCT 
                    (select equipo.nombre from equipo where codigo=partidos.equipo1)as eq1, 
                    (select equipo.nombre from equipo where codigo=partidos.equipo2)as eq2, 
                    torneo.nombre as Torneo, 
                    partidos.cancha,
                    partidos.ronda,
                    partidos.equipo1 as ceq1, 
                    partidos.equipo2 as ceq2 
                    FROM 
                    partidos 
                    INNER JOIN equiposdeltorneo 
                    ON partidos.equipo1 = equiposdeltorneo.equipoCodigo 
                    INNER JOIN equipo
                    ON equiposdeltorneo.equipoCodigo = equipo.codigo 
                    INNER JOIN torneo 
                    ON partidos.idTorneo = torneo.idTorneo 
                    INNER JOIN cancha 
                    ON partidos.cancha = cancha.numeroCancha 
                    WHERE torneo.idtorneo = 11 AND partidos.ronda = 1
                </sql:query>
```

the problem is in the foreach

```
<c:forEach var="row" items="${calendario.rows}" varStatus="vs">
```

when I try `${row}` the `ceq1` and `ceq2` does not exists I think
this is for aliases. Somebody knows why??

Answer (score -1):

Guess this is a bug .. found a similar stack overflow question .. check  the below link for post with answer.

I think it as a bug may be it is a feature not provided .

the below link provides a detail how to call column names ... (just the heading names of every coloumn).

[How to access duplicate column names with JSTL sql:query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14431907/how-to-access-duplicate-column-names-with-jstl-sqlquery)

But i would suggest to use rowbyindex instead of rows.

```
<c:forEach var="row" items="${calendario.rowsByIndex}" >
```

and print it out like this:

```
<c:out value="${row[0]}"/>
```

just like an array the value get stored from 0 to the number of selected coloumn's.