# How to print column names returned by sql:query?

Tags: jsp, jstl

```
<sql:query var="TableRow" dataSource="jdbc/db">
   SELECT * from table1;
</sql:query>
```

How to display the names of columns in `table1` table? I know how to access the individual rows using Tablerow.rowsByIndex, but don't know how to display the column names themselves.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access duplicate column names with JSTL sql:query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14431907/how-to-access-duplicate-column-names-with-jstl-sqlquery)

Answer (score 1):

```
<sql:query sql="SELECT * from table1" var="TableRow" dataSource="jdbc/db">
 <c:forEach var="colName" items=${TableRow.columnsNames}>
    ${colName}
 </c:forEach>
</sql:query>
```

Move sql query into attribute, and have a loop for columnsName on query result

Comment: Thanks, I will try this later in the evening.

Comment: @YangDaniel, you have already closed `<sql:query>` with `/>`. so you don't need to add last line.